# Unknown member 'UpdateSourceTrigger' on element 'Binding'

Tags: xaml, data-binding, binding, c++-cx, updatesourcetrigger

I'm currently trying out C++/CX and XAML as a Windows 8 App - Project. It looks like things are working out great, but right now I stumbled on this error: 
*'Unknown member 'error WMC0011 UpdateSourceTrigger' on element 'Binding'*.

I'm trying to use the UpdateSourceTrigger on a TextBox with the value 'PropertyChanged' to update the source after every keystroke like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Bord.Naam, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Anyone knows how I'll be able to update the source after every key stroke?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 development does not support UpdateSourceTrigger. This is supported in Windows 8.1 apps, if you upgrade your App to 8.1 you will be able to use it.

This blog post shows more updates on bindings on Windows 8.1 apps:

http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2013/07/windows-8-1-data-binding/

Comment: Thanks, I just targeted 8.1 with my app.. Pity we need VS 2013 to target 8.1